# get tag content by javascript of tag that "outside the document"

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I have this HTML source :

```
<div id='fbResponse' style='display:none'>{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}</div>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     ....
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initFB()" style="text-align: center">
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

How do i get the content-text of the div tag with id "fbResponse",
I tried already the function

```
document.getElementById('tag id'),
```

It doesn't work ,i think it is because that the tag :

```
<div id='fbResponse' style='display:none'>{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}</div>
```

is out of the "document" .

**EDIT:**
The browser which I need it to work on is mobile Safari (iOS)

Comment: Why is there html with stuff outside the document?

Comment: and why not move it inside the body?

Comment: put the div inside body for crying out loud, you already know this so this question is not valid. It's like asking code with syntax errors to work, the only fix for that is to fix the frigging syntax.

Comment: What do you mean, "out of the document?"

Comment: I'm getting it from a server , it is not my work . I'm looking for a solution for this problem .

Comment: Which part do you get from a server?

Comment: @gdoron : Above the tag - <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @kuh-chan This is a web page which she didn't wrote. she doesn't have any control over its format. If she could move this div inside the body - she would have.

Comment: @Avrahma kapara, It's an invalid HTML! you can't write nodes above the root!

Comment: which browser? In Firefox it's working fine with the above code

Comment: `document.getElementById('fbResponse')`

IE9, Firefox 12 and Opera 11.64 are doing it with the code you've posted and getElementById. Maybe you misspelled the id?

Comment: @gdoron Gever, I *know* it's not a valid HTML (nor XML) but the question is "is there a way to access it anyway". If not - please post an answer - "It's impossible with this format". Don't tell her to change the HTML couse she just can't...

Comment: It [**does** work](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/foo.html) (even in mobile Safari); browsers are very good at recovering from this kind of junk.

Comment: @Quentin. You put the div inside the `<body>` it's outside the whole document in her page...

Comment: @gdoron — I copy / pasted the code from the question. If the div appears in the body then you are probably viewing a serialisation of the DOM (after the browser has attempted to recover from the errors) instead of the source.

Comment: @Quentin you're right...

Comment: I see your test page , but it stil not work for me on objective-c function call. i'm calling the function "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('fbResponse').innerHTML" and it return empt string .

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='fbResponse' style='display:none'>{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}</div>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(document.getElementById('fbResponse'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a log even in IE... I think you just did something wrong